# Which is better Scala style?

Tags: scala, coding-style

Although I know this might be purely preference based, I have a question about style.
Given the code below:

```
map {
  updateWriteResult => 
    logger.debug(....
    Utils.wrFeedback(.....
    auditAction(....
    //HTTP 200
    Ok(".....                                
}
```

Is the above formatting considered better style than the below?

```
map { updateWriteResult => 
  logger.debug(....
  Utils.wrFeedback(.....
  auditAction(....
  //HTTP 200
  Ok(".....                                
}
```

Comment: Unless there's an official Scala style guide that specifies which should be preferred, this is entirely opinion based and offtopic. When I wrote Scala though, I preferred the latter. I feel it makes it clearer that the body is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations) (last paragraph), it should be the latter.